# Inserting tree by using constructor without using other function

Tags: c++

I tried to create a simple binary tree by using constructor

```
TreeNode(int val) : val(val), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
```

I am totally lost on creating binary tree. I can create a tree by creating insert function but by utilizing constructor i am not too sure.

``````````
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;
    TreeNode(int val) : val(val), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
};


TreeNode* newNode(int data)
{
    TreeNode* Node = new TreeNode();
    Node->val = data;
    Node->left = NULL;
    Node->right = NULL;

    return(Node);
}

bool isSameTree(TreeNode* p, TreeNode* q) {
    bool left;
    bool right;
    if (p == nullptr&&q == nullptr)
        return true;
    else if (p->val == q->val) {
        left = isSameTree(p->left, q->left);
        right = isSameTree(p->right, q->right);
        return left && right;
    }
    else return false;
}

void print(TreeNode* root) {
    if (root != nullptr) {
        print(root->left);
        cout << root->val << " ";
        print(root->right);
    }

}

int main() {



    TreeNode *root = newNode(1);
    root->left = newNode(2);
    root->right = newNode(3);
    root->left->left = newNode(4);
    root->left->right = newNode(5);


    TreeNode *root1 = newNode(1);
    root1->left = newNode(2);
    root1->right = newNode(3);
    root1->left->left = newNode(4);
    root1->left->right = newNode(5);

    if (isSameTree(root, root1))
        cout << "there are same tree" << endl;
    else 
        cout << "there are not same tree" << endl;

}

`````````
``````````

Comment: The first step of understanding would be to think about what exactly you would like to ask here.

Comment: I think he wants to use the constructor rather than using newNode function.

Comment: There is a bug in `isSameTree`– consider the case where exactly one of the subtree pointers is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a one-parameter constructor that takes the node value and sets both pointers to `nullptr`.
That is, it has the same effect as

```
Node->val = data;
Node->left = NULL;
Node->right = NULL;
```

In other words, you can replace all uses of `newNode(x)` with `new TreeNode(x)`.

(By the way: stick to `nullptr`, don't throw `NULL` into the mix.)

You might want to add another constructor that takes the subtrees as well

```
TreeNode(int val, TreeNode* l, TreeNode* r)
```

which would let you write

```
TreeNode *root = new TreeNode(1, 
                              new TreeNode(2, new TreeNode(4), new TreeNode(5)), 
                              new TreeNode(3));
```

Answer (score -1):

Using constructor is done like:

`root->left = new TreeNode(2);`

Answer (score -3):

you can use class it's better than struct if you want to create a simple binary tree by using constructor

Comment: Can you explain why you think this would be better?